# globalize2 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have strange globalize2 problem. I'm trying to use globalize 2 and acts_as_textiled and acts_as_commentable. For example - lets we have Post model, that acts_as_commentable. From console

```
p = Post.find 1
c = p.comments.find 1
```

works fine, but in browser - nothing displayed

Similar, when Post contains

```
acts_as_textiled :body
```

from console body is containing correct data, but in browser i see nothing :(

Any ideas how to correct it?

Upd: "nothing displayed" means,
that for code like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
translates :title, :body
acts_as_textiled  :body
end
```

on access to Post.body i've got nil, but on disabled globalize2 or
acts_as_textiled body returns his value. I've tried with different
locales - the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you performed the necessary migrations? For localised content you should remove the localised fields in the main table (posts) and create a table for the localisations, like this:

```
create_table "post_translations", :force => true do |t|
  t.string  "locale"
  t.integer "product_id"
  t.string  "title"
  t.text    "body"
end
```

Just guessing here :)

Comment: Of course - all migrations was performed and fields removed. i've received recommendation to use this code to solve problem - http://gist.github.com/169709